# How to overlay an image above all activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to overlay an image above all activities after some operation to have a feel like phone is locked. How can I do this programmatically in android ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `FrameLayout` at the end of you XML layout file with an `ImageView` and `"match_parent"` dimension for both length and height. Set it's visibility to "gone" in the XML layout file. and the problematically in your code change it's visibility to visible to show this full screen Image and hide all the other components that are laid below it.

For example in your XML file put this at the end of the XML:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lockScreenLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" >
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"          
       android:background="@drawable/your_iamge"
       android:contentDescription="@drawable/your_iamge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So it would be the child of your root xml element.

and then in code, do this:

```
lockScreenLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.lockScreenLayout);
lockScreenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution consists in setting your image as the background of the root view of your activities.